# Replacing a very old toilet

Tags: toilet

Old toilet has lead 'flange' with no bolts. Toilet was screwed down with bolts embedded in  the floor.

I have subsequently cleaned this, the lead flange has some crut on it that isn't going away, but all the loose debris is gone.

Plumber wants me to cut tile away to seat toilet on subfloor.

This seems wrong to me. It looks to me as if I can use [this Danco kit](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Danco-HydroSeat-Stainless-Steel-6-88-in-in-Toilet-Flange-For-Fits-Most/1000034733), which screws down atop a wax ring and provides bolts to mount the toilet. Even, really, I don't see why couldn't drill through the tile and install the usual semi-circular brackets with bolts around the old lead flange and seat the toilet conventionally, but the Danco device looks friendlier to a novice. Am I missing something?

[image: What Remains]

Comment: So you have hired a plumber but don't like his recommendations and are seeking "better" information from random folks here.  Hmmm...

Comment: Have you considered how far off the wall that is, for trying to match to a modern S-trap set? Unless you're going to build out cabinet behind [in which case all solutions change] then you're going to have quite a gap. Can't see the wall in the pic, but I'd be seriously considering back-filling that old drain & setting up a modern P-Trap into the wall.

Comment: @jwh20 - if that's authentic period [deco] tile, I'd shoot the plumber for suggesting pulling it up, unless he was also suggesting putting it all back again, good as new.

Comment: Can't imagine why you would want to cut the tile as opposed to repairing the flange. I like your idea better than the plumbers but I would wait, someone should come along here and recommend the best product for your repair.

Comment: The total age of the two plumbers the firm sent out is less than the age of my house. @jwh20, I have seen pretty strong evidence that some folks on this site are experienced professionals who might have some relevant experience.

Comment: @Tetsujin it's a standard 12" offset. Some toilets come in that offset. Some do not. Since there is also historical tile in the wall, I'm not interested in messing with the wall. I have, in fact, successfully set the toilet today.